# How to solve this differential equation 2

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

\begin{align}
     \ x\frac{dy}{dx}-4y &= x^6e^x \\\\
   \end{align}
By dividing on x we get :

\begin{align}
\ \frac{dy}{dx}-4\frac{y}{x}=x^5e^x 
\end{align}
Now I got the integrating factor"by e^integralOf(4/x) that's going to be : 
\begin{align}
\ x^{-4}
\end{align}

By multiply the I.F in every side then Integral I got :

\begin{align}
\ \frac{-x^{-3}}{3} +4\frac{x^{-6}}{6}y=xe^x -x+C 
\end{align}

That's What I got , but the final answer in the source that I study from shows another final answer . What's the wrong in my solution ?

Note : The final answer in the source is :

\begin{align}
\ y=x^4[xe^x-e^x]+C 
\end{align}

Comment: I belive it should be $yx^{-4}= \int xe^x$

Comment: @user376343 I think that my mistake should be in the last step in the multiplying but I.F then integrate

Comment: @Alexandros could you kindly write your answer down maybe that's gonna be helpful to get my mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you multiply the ODE $\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{4y}{x} = x^5e^x$ by the integrating factor $x^{-4}$ and then we get 
$$ x^{-4} \frac{dy}{dx} -4yx^{-5}  = xe^x$$
which then reduces to 
$$ \frac{d(yx^{-4})}{dx} = xe^x$$
and so we integrate both sides $$C+yx^{-4} = \int{xe^x}\,dx$$
Then we use integration by parts
$$\int{xe^x}\,dx = xe^x - \int{e^x}\,dx = xe^x - e^x + K$$
and so $$y = x^5e^x - x^4e^x +Lx^4$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}-\frac{4y}{x}=x^5e^x \\\text{I.F.}=\exp\biggl({-\int 4\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}}\biggr)=\frac{1}{x^4}\\\implies y=x^4\int x e^x\mathrm dx$$

---

In your case you made a mistake in step $3$, it should be $(yx^{-4})'=xe^x$. Can you proceed?

Comment: Yes I can do that 
but I think my mistake before that , I mean when we going to multiply by I.F of both side then integral , can you show me this step only ? That's only step what confused me

Comment: Notice that the $\text{I.F.}=v(x)$(say) is chosen so as to write the side with the unknown function as $(y\cdot v(x))'$. That is in fact why the $\text{I.F.}$ is $\exp \int P \mathrm dx$ for the general linear differential equation $y'+Py=Q$ where $P$ and $Q$ are functions of $x$.